# \MakeUppercase fails to capitalize macro retrieved via \DTLfetch from datatool package

Tags: datatool

## Problem statement

When I try to apply the `\MakeUppercase` command to a macro whose value is retrieved from a `.csv` table via `\DTLfetch` from the `datatool` package, I get a compilation error.

I am looking for a solution that overcomes this problem.

## Minimal (non-)working example (MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
\def\myvariable{\DTLfetch{data}{Key}{Variable}{Value}}%

\begin{document}

\myvariable\\% This works as expected
\MakeUppercase{\myvariable}% TODO: This breaks compilation

\end{document}
```

with `data.csv` consisting of:

```
Key,Value
Variable,1f.45
```

## Error received upon compilation

Trying to compile the above example results in the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   3
l.11 \MakeUppercase{\myvariable}
```

Comment: Problem seems to be specific to `\DTLfetch` - it seems that it is overcome at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248965/uppercase-with-datatool-does-not-work by using `\DTLassignfirstmatch` instead (which does not suit my situation, however). I'll amend the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\DTLfetch` is not expandable, so it can not work in the argument of `\MakeUppercase`, even if hidden inside `\myvariable`.

Instead, you can use `\DTLgetvalueforkey` to assign the value to `\myvariable`, then `\myvariable` contains the actual value instead of the `\DTLfetch` command and can be used inside of `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
\DTLgetvalueforkey\myvariable{Value}{data}{Key}{Variable}

\begin{document}

\myvariable\\% This works as expected
\MakeUppercase{\myvariable}% This works too.

\end{document}
```